# Bootstrap data table footer row

Tags: php, datatables

I want to get total of approved cadre,permanent,contract....so on footer row in data table.

I tried some code modification. but it's not working. This is the script of my code

```
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $CadreId; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $designation; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $Service; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $Class; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $salcode; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $sLevel; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $AppCadre; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $permanent; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $casual; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $contract; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $vacancy; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $Exceed; ?></td> 



        </tr>


            <?php   
            }

        }

         ?>
                </tbody>

                    <tfoot align="right">
    <tr class="totalColumn"><th></th><th></th><th></th><th></th><th></th><th></tr>
</tfoot>
</table>
```

```
<script>
```

var totals=[0,0,0];
        $(document).ready(function(){

```
        var $dataRows=$("#sum_table tr:not('.totalColumn, .titlerow')");

        $dataRows.each(function() {
            $(this).find('.rowDataSd').each(function(i){        
                totals[i]+=parseInt( $(this).html());
            });
        });
        $("#sum_table td.totalCol").each(function(i){  
            $(this).html("total:"+totals[i]);
        });

    });
```

How to fix this?

Comment: Can you elaborate further and what have you already tried to do and what kind of errors you're getting?

Comment: Hey, as of now your question is breaking SO's rules. I can tell you straight away that nobody is going to sift through >1k lines of code to find something like that. "I have an issue and this is my code" is not a valid question on SO. Please refer to [Minimal Complete and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Thank you!